# 'lapacke.h' file not found error when installing libact

Tags: python, macos, lapack, openblas

I am trying to install the python `libact` package on my computer using [the tutorial](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact#installation-options) on their github page. I'm using python 3.7.5 on macOS.

I have installed `openblas` as a requirement which consists of `lapacke.h` header file. However, when I type any of the commands for installing `libact`, I get the error `libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c:5:10: fatal error: 'lapacke.h' file not found`. I searched this issue on github and related questions on SO and none of these solutions have worked for me.

I have tried adding the `lapacke.h` directory to my path environmental variable as suggested [here](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact/issues/170), reinstalling `gcc`, and installing the package using other methods but none of them have worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full message when I try to install the package:

```
Collecting libact
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/8c/1f57cbe9e6b647afa14f8446c20caa2343fa26153be179e5a89060cd6ec2/libact-0.1.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (1.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn<=0.19.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (0.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (0.29.14)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from libact) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->libact) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->libact) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->libact) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->libact) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib->libact) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: libact
  Building wheel for libact (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-install-6402bf85/libact/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-qhxixz3i --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Platform Detection: Mac OS X. Link to openblas...
  Build VarianceReduction...
  Build HintSVM...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
  copying libact/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
  copying libact/base/interfaces.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
  copying libact/base/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
  copying libact/base/dataset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  copying libact/models/perceptron.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  copying libact/models/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  copying libact/models/sklearn_adapter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  copying libact/models/logistic_regression.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  copying libact/models/svm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
  copying libact/models/multilabel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
  copying libact/models/multilabel/binary_relevance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
  copying libact/models/multilabel/dummy_clf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
  copying libact/labelers/ideal_labeler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
  copying libact/labelers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
  copying libact/labelers/interactive_labeler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/random_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/hintsvm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/quire.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/active_learning_by_learning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/variance_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/query_by_committee.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/density_weighted_meta.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/density_weighted_uncertainty_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  copying libact/query_strategies/uncertainty_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/cost_sensitive_reference_pair_encoding.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/maximum_margin_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/binary_minimization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/multilabel_with_auxiliary_learner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/adaptive_active_learning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/expected_error_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/mdsp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/active_learning_with_cost_embedding.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/hierarchical_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/utils
  copying libact/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/utils
  running build_ext
  building 'libact.query_strategies._variance_reduction' extension
  Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
  Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
  C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers

  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction
  compile options: '-I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c'
  extra options: '-std=c11'
  clang: libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c
  libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c:5:10: fatal error: 'lapacke.h' file not found
  #include <lapacke.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.o -std=c11" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libact
  Running setup.py clean for libact
Failed to build libact
Installing collected packages: libact
  Running setup.py install for libact ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-install-6402bf85/libact/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-record-26z7vy46/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Platform Detection: Mac OS X. Link to openblas...
    Build VarianceReduction...
    Build HintSVM...
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
    copying libact/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
    copying libact/base/interfaces.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
    copying libact/base/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
    copying libact/base/dataset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/base
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    copying libact/models/perceptron.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    copying libact/models/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    copying libact/models/sklearn_adapter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    copying libact/models/logistic_regression.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    copying libact/models/svm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
    copying libact/models/multilabel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
    copying libact/models/multilabel/binary_relevance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
    copying libact/models/multilabel/dummy_clf.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/models/multilabel
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
    copying libact/labelers/ideal_labeler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
    copying libact/labelers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
    copying libact/labelers/interactive_labeler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/labelers
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/random_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/hintsvm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/quire.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/active_learning_by_learning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/variance_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/query_by_committee.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/density_weighted_meta.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/density_weighted_uncertainty_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    copying libact/query_strategies/uncertainty_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/cost_sensitive_reference_pair_encoding.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/maximum_margin_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/binary_minimization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/multilabel_with_auxiliary_learner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    copying libact/query_strategies/multilabel/adaptive_active_learning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multilabel
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/expected_error_reduction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/mdsp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/active_learning_with_cost_embedding.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    copying libact/query_strategies/multiclass/hierarchical_sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/multiclass
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/utils
    copying libact/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/utils
    running build_ext
    building 'libact.query_strategies._variance_reduction' extension
    Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
    Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
    C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction
    compile options: '-I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c'
    extra options: '-std=c11'
    clang: libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c
    libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c:5:10: fatal error: 'lapacke.h' file not found
    #include <lapacke.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.o -std=c11" failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-install-6402bf85/libact/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-record-26z7vy46/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jl/ldl4kwz12vgdf44bt2nc70zw0000gn/T/pip-install-6402bf85/libact/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. install openblas and lapack:

> ```
> brew install openblas    
> brew install lapack
> ```

2. Then add them in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or just execute these commands in your terminal session:

> ```
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include"
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig"
>
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
> ```

Now, there is just one problem left:
 `openblas` and `lapack` has a function with the same name but different signatures and hence you will get this error if you run `pip install libact`:

```
libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.c:8:13: error: conflicting types for 'dgesvd_'
    extern void LAPACK_dgesvd( char* jobu, char* jobvt, int* m, int* n, double* a,...
```

3. One fix is to let go of the **variance reduction algorithm** in libact for now! The rest will work just fine:

```
LIBACT_BUILD_HINTSVM=1  LIBACT_BUILD_VARIANCE_REDUCTION=0 pip install git+https://github.com/ntucllab/libact.git
```

This will install libact without error.